# File encoded in Latin-1 but read in UTF-8 could deal in any problem?

Tags: html, utf-8, iso-8859-1

Problem is the following:

In a translation system, we use keys to refer to the same "word" in different languages,
For example: For key common.close

common.close in Spanish = Cerrar

common.close in English = Close

This keys are stored in a file encoded in latin1 but database table storing keys is encoded in UTF-8.
From my front side, we are accessing keys by reading the file (encoded in latin-1) but our html specifies encoding as:

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
```

Our problem is that in the process of creating/editing keys from front side, some keys are disappearing from the file.
This could be lead by the encoding difference?
Even if this isn't the reason, file encoded in latin-1 but shown in utf-8 may cause any problem?

Regards, Víctor.

Comment: It will break as soon as you use a character above code point 128 or which isn't in ISO-8859-1.

Comment: @Quentin the thing is that in front side, every character above code point 128 is shown correctly even if in the file appears as follows: \uxxxx

Comment: An escape sequence that only uses ASCII characters isn't using characters above code point 128

Comment: @Quentin Sorry but I didn't understand,
A escape sequence like \uxxxx isn't above code point 128?